# Loop Toggle for different ID Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this following script to toggle (show and hide):

```
function btnClass1(where, pval, nval){
var x=$("#btn1-Bln ").val();
if (x == 'Show '){
where.title='Show ';
}
else{
where.title='Hide ';
}
where.value=(where.value == nval) ? pval : nval;
container=document.getElementById("containerXd");
container.style.display=(container.style.display == 'inline-block') ? 'none' : 'inline-block';
container.style.visibility=(container.style.visibility == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible'
```

;

I have many IDs to toggle, say, it's about 24 different IDs.
When I use the code it works fine, I just change `#btnClass1` to `#btnClass2` and 3, etc as well as `#btn1-Bln`, and `containerXd`.

But, I feel it's not efficient to build every IDs with new block of the script (again and again). 
In this case, I need a simple script to represent all IDs in a web page.
Do you have other best suggestion for me, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add two new params to your function for the buttonSelector and the containerSelector. In your example, you would pass in "#btn1-Bln" and "containerXd" for these new params, respectively. Then, use these new variables rather than the hard-coded strings in your function body. This will allow you to use your single existing function with any buttons and containers.

Comment: Thanks, I try to do what you mean and it works. I'm learning about it hardly now.